# modify tab length for eclim-java-format

Tags: spacemacs, whitespace, tabs

So I'm trying to use eclim with spacemacs and I have this function called `eclim-java-format` which reformat the text as in eclipse. The problems is that it reformats tabs as tabs and not as space and it sets tabs length to 2 and I prefer working with 4.

Do you know how I can tweek these tabs settings?

Even with emacs but not spacemacs answer is fine. I may try to figure out the rest of it.

Comment: Have a look at the links from a search for ["emacs tabs spaces"](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=emacs+tabs+spaces&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I after at least 2h of searching I finally found [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingJava)! Which says :

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (setq c-basic-offset 4
                                  tab-width 4
                                  indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

and I put it in my .spacemacs in user-config function and it worked :D